# DV-AVI in DivX Plus Player and VirtualDub - playback issue

Tags: windows-xp, avi, virtualdub, dv

I have an AVI-video which I had (digitally) transferred from a DV camera to my PC. The video contains errors at the beginning most likely because the DV tape was pretty old.

When playing this video in the DivX Plus Player I get some picture artefacts and some high noise peaks of the sound. These stops after two seconds.
When I'm playing this video in VirtualDub (where I want to cut it) I get the same picture artefacts. But the sound errors (those loud high peaks) lasts ten seconds. These sound errors are also contained in the cutted video.

Why does the video have *more errors* when played in VirtualDub? I think because of different codecs which are used for decoding the video? How can I change the codec which VirtualDub uses for decoding? I have installed ffdshow for this but it seems that it is not used because I don't get the ffdshow icon in the taskbar when playing the video in VirtualDub. When playing in DivX Player Plus I get this icon.